# How to add values to HTTP response header using php

Tags: php, curl

So far I manage to get HTTP response header from this

```
$ch = curl_init();<br/>
$url="http://localhost/PHP_Projects/Test/response.php";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

$headers = get_headers_from_curl_response($response);

foreach($headers as $x => $x_value){<br/>
    print $x.": ".$x_value;<br/>
}

function get_headers_from_curl_response($response)
{<br/>
    $headers = array();

    $header_text = substr($response, 0, strpos($response, "\r\n\r\n"));

    foreach (explode("\r\n", $header_text) as $i => $line)
        if ($i === 0)
            $headers['http_code'] = $line;
        else
        {
            list ($key, $value) = explode(': ', $line);

            $headers[$key] = $value;
        }

    return $headers;
}
```

The out put from this is like

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Date: Thu, 07 May 2015 03:26:26 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.6.8
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.8
Content-Length: 128
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

but I want to add some more to this like

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Path=/application_uri
Freeflow: FC
charge: Y
amount: 100
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Content-Type: UTF-8
Content-Length: 20
```

Comment: Which headers exactly do you need to add?

Comment: I want to add these 
Path=/application_uri
Freeflow: FC
charge: Y
amount: 100
but i don't know how to get 
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: max-age=0
These as well

Comment: You posted the curl script that makes a request from the client side. The response headers are returned by the server side script response.php. We need to see response.php to help.

Comment: I don't have one I do have only HTTP request wich is a URL I want  to extract that url and response. http://127.0.0.1:8080/application_uri?userid=app1&password=app1pwd&MSISDN=919845098450&MSC=919845098000&input=121 I'm sorry I have no idea how to do this

Answer (score 2):

```
$headers = array( 'Path: application_uri',
                  'Freeflow: FC',
                  'charge: Y',
                  'amount: 100',
                 );
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
```